# ReactJs code Reading/Connecting two times to my APi

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJs and while I am trying to connect to my API (which is SSE and I would like to stay connected in order to retrieve when new even comes from the server) it prints/consumes the same message 2 times on first page load and later when new event happens it even consumes it couple times, I am not sure if it opens the connection multiple times or I am doing something wrong? Code looks like below

```
export default function News() {
const [newsList, setNews] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/news")

source.addEventListener('open', () => {
  console.log('SSE opened!');
});

source.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
   var message = JSON.parse(event.data)
  console.log(message);
  setNews(newsList => [...newsList, message]);
});

source.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
  console.error('Error: ',  e);
});
}, []);


return (
 <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark" size="sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Published at</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {newsList.map(({ id, title, published_utc, i }) => (
        <tr key={id}>
            <td>{published_utc}</td>
            <td>{title}</td>
        </tr>
    ))}
   </tbody>
 </Table>
);
}
```

And above code prints duplicates in console. I was calling endpoint from browser or postman and I see that backed returns unique data without any issue, something wrong with my UI impl

Comment: Get rid of the event listeners and use the returns from the calls your making.

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/news");
    source.onopen(() =>{
      console.log("SSE opened!");
    })
    source.onerror(
      (err) => console.error(err)
    );

    source.onmessage(((event) => {
      var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log(message);
      setNews((newsList) => [...newsList, message]);
    }))
  }, []);

Comment: or something like that, you don't want to be adding listeners to your app in an effect and your not removing them in the return of the effect currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely due to the double invocation behavior that Strict Mode introduces. React Strict Mode intentionally double-invokes certain functions, including useEffect, to help detect potential side-effects and other issues in your application.

You can just comment out <React.StrictMode> in index.js of your src dir, as shown below

```js
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>

  // </React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: You are my day saver :D thanks a lot